# How to get value between two span id in python using soap

Tags: django, python-3.x, soap, web-scraping

I want to get all values between two span id for example from  RAOCSTD2018-10-27 to RAOCSTD2018-10-30 how can i achieve that. Below is my current code but can only get one value from one pecific span id.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<tr id="RAOCSTD-dates" class="availability selected">
                                <td title="3" class="dt20181027 d6">
                                                <span id="RAOCSTD2018-10-27">$739</span></td><td title="3" class="dt20181028 d0">
                                                <span id="RAOCSTD2018-10-28">$686  </span></td><td title="3" class="dt20181029 d1"> <span id="RAOCSTD2018-10-29">$686 </span></td><td title="3" class="dt20181030 d2">  <span id="RAOCSTD2018-10-30"> $686  </span></td>
                        </tr>"""

 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

 allvaluesbetweentwospanid = {}
for li_tag in soup.find_all('tr', {'class':'availability selected'}):
        # for span_tag in li_tag.find_all('li', {'class':'list-group-item'}):

        value = li_tag.find('span', {'id':room_instance + chek_in}).text
        allvaluesbetweentwospanid [] = value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have an easier time if you formatted your code more carefully. I've cleaned it up and added some invalid examples to the HTML to check that the date filter is actually working. Some of the values will obviously have to be set dynamically instead of manually, but this should get you pretty close where you want to go.
    from datetime import datetime

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"

html = """
<tr id="RAOCSTD-dates" class="availability selected">
    <td title="3" class="dt20181025 d6">
        <span id="RAOCSTD2018-10-25">$839</span>
    </td>
    <td title="3" class="dt20181027 d6">
        <span id="RAOCSTD2018-10-27">$739</span>
    </td>
    <td title="3" class="dt20181028 d0">
        <span id="RAOCSTD2018-10-28">$686</span>
    </td>
    <td title="3" class="dt20181029 d1"> 
        <span id="RAOCSTD2018-10-29">$686</span>
    </td>
    <td title="3" class="dt20181030 d2">  
        <span id="RAOCSTD2018-10-30">$686</span>
    </td>
    <td title="3" class="dt20181101 d2">  
        <span id="RAOCSTD2018-11-01">$686</span>
    </td>
    <td title="3" class="dt20181102 d2">  
        <span id="RAOCSTD2018-11-02">$686</span>
    </td>
</tr>
"""

room_instance = "RAOCSTD"
start_date = datetime.strptime("2018-10-27", DATE_FORMAT)
end_date = datetime.strptime("2018-10-30", DATE_FORMAT)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

values = []

def id_filter(i):
    if not (i and i.startswith(room_instance)):
        return False

    id_date = datetime.strptime(i.split(room_instance)[-1], DATE_FORMAT)

    return start_date <= id_date <= end_date

for tr in soup.find_all("tr", {"class":"availability selected"}):
    values.extend(
        span.text for span in
        tr.findAll(
            "span",
            id=id_filter,
        )
    )

print(values)
```